I want to change values of a string to upper case if its even. What am I doing wrong?
def func(string):
    stringlist= string.split()
    stringlist =[]
    for pos in string:
        stringlist.append(pos)
    for pan in stringlist:
        if pan %2 ==0:
            pan.upper()
        
       
   
print(stringlist)

func("Hello")

Tried everything I know. I just get an error about TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Hello, It is very unclear what your function is supposed to achieve. the pan%2 == 0 can't work because pan is a string and the modulo operation is used for integers. Provide some example of inputs and expected output so we can help you.

You could make use of enumerate, which returns index and value within the string:
def func(string):
    return ''.join(char.upper() if index % 2 == 0 else char for index, char in enumerate(string))

print(func("Hello"))
HeLlO


I didn't even know what enumerate was. Thats really good too. I'm using that instead.  Thanks.
